# Has any teacher said that all classes of scripture have the same essential message?

Tags: scripture

Just to name a few classes

Vedas
Brahmanas,Aranyakas
Upanishads
Itihasapuranas

Has any teacher said that each class, taken as a whole, is conveying the same essential message?